# Delete all documents from Solr that have a certain empty field

Tags: solr

Querying for those documents works with: `"fq=-myfield:[* TO *]"`.

But how can I delete all those? It seems that the delete syntax `update?stream.body=<delete><query>...` accepts only a query, no filters...

Comment: A filter is a query, so you should be able to issue it as a query?

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer should be: `-myfield:*` or even `-myfield:[* TO *]`, but the `:` is mandatory.

This is is an example with curl:

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/collection/update \ 
  -H "Content-Type: text/xml" \  
  --data-binary '<delete><query>-myfield:*</query></delete>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Only pass `-myfield[* TO *]` in query tag. Do not pass `fq` parameter. Then it will work I feel. Once I had to delete all documents with id that contained word  `"data"` in the id field string, I just passed `id:*data*` between query tags, and it worked. Let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Could work - unfortunately I always get:

"ava.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.solr.query.SolrRangeQuery.createDocSet(SolrRangeQuery.java:156)
 at org.apache.solr.query.SolrRangeQuery.access$200(SolrRangeQuery.java:57)"

which seems like exactly this bug regarding non-numeric range queries (like mine): https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9235

Comment: Ok will check with a data set from my side and will let you know